# I can't figure out why I'm getting an undefined reference issue when calling methods within my header file

Tags: c, linux, undefined

I am getting the following errors within my test file (memalloc_test.c) when I call methods defined within the header for my other file (memalloc.c)...

```
gcc memalloc_test.c -o memalloc_test
/tmp/ccvO6oS7.o: In function `main':
memalloc_test.c:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `my_mallinfo'
memalloc_test.c:(.text+0x29): undefined reference to `my_malloc'
memalloc_test.c:(.text+0x4d): undefined reference to `my_mallinfo'
memalloc_test.c:(.text+0x6d): undefined reference to `my_free'
memalloc_test.c:(.text+0x81): undefined reference to `my_mallinfo'
memalloc_test.c:(.text+0x9f): undefined reference to `my_malloc'
memalloc_test.c:(.text+0xc8): undefined reference to `my_mallinfo'
memalloc_test.c:(.text+0xd4): undefined reference to `my_free'
memalloc_test.c:(.text+0xe0): undefined reference to `my_free'
memalloc_test.c:(.text+0xf4): undefined reference to `my_mallinfo'
memalloc_test.c:(.text+0x100): undefined reference to `my_free'
memalloc_test.c:(.text+0x10c): undefined reference to `my_free'
memalloc_test.c:(.text+0x120): undefined reference to `my_mallinfo'
memalloc_test.c:(.text+0x12a): undefined reference to `my_malloc'
memalloc_test.c:(.text+0x142): undefined reference to `my_mallinfo'
memalloc_test.c:(.text+0x14e): undefined reference to `my_free'
memalloc_test.c:(.text+0x162): undefined reference to `my_mallinfo'
memalloc_test.c:(.text+0x16c): undefined reference to `my_mallopt'
memalloc_test.c:(.text+0x176): undefined reference to `my_malloc'
memalloc_test.c:(.text+0x18e): undefined reference to `my_mallinfo'
memalloc_test.c:(.text+0x198): undefined reference to `my_malloc'
memalloc_test.c:(.text+0x1b0): undefined reference to `my_mallinfo'
memalloc_test.c:(.text+0x1bc): undefined reference to `my_free'
memalloc_test.c:(.text+0x1d0): undefined reference to `my_mallinfo'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My header file is as follows...

```
//Header    
#ifndef MEMALLOC_H
#define MEMALLOC_H

#define BLOCK_SIZE 500
#define NUMBER_POINTERS 10

void* my_malloc(int size);
void my_free(void *ptr);
void my_mallopt(int policy);
void my_mallinfo();
extern char *my_malloc_error();

#endif
```

I am very sure that my header is calling the correctly named methods within "memalloc.c". Currently my make file assembles memalloc, but I am manually trying to compile the test, which is where I fail. In case it's relevant, here is my make file.

```
CFLAGS = -c -Wall
CFLAGS+= -g
LDFLAGS = 
SOURCES= memalloc.c memalloc_test.c memalloc.h
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)
EXECUTABLE=memalloc
all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    gcc $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
.c.o:
    gcc $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
clean:
    rm -rf *.o *~ memalloc
```

Comment: Try `gcc memalloc.c memalloc_test.c -o memalloc_test` as all the functions are defined in memalloc.c

Comment: Aside from completely unnecessary `memalloc.h` specified as a `SOURCE`, I don't see any problems with your makefile in its current form. In my experiment everything compiles and links by GCC make without any problems. I suspect that something is wrong with your function definitions. (Which you haven't shown yet. What you have in your header file is declarations, not definitions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you link your program, you must specify all relevant object files (and libraries if required) at the `gcc` call. But, at this command line, you specified only one:

```
gcc memalloc_test.c -o memalloc_test
```

Your makefile almost does the right work, but you should remove the header file in the `SOURCES` line, so that, it looks like this:

```
SOURCES= memalloc.c memalloc_test.c
```

Then `OBJECTS` gets assigned `memalloc.o memalloc_test.o` and the gcc command will be (after replacing the variables):

```
gcc memalloc.o memalloc_test.o -o memalloc
```

Further note: you may change the executable name to `memalloc_test`.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell:

`gcc memalloc_test.c -o memalloc_test`

This line is compiling memalloc_test.c into an object file but not adding the memalloc.c 's object file which is where the reference to those functions are defined.